# Is there any SIP-VOIP plugin in smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I want to add VOIP call in my project, i checked all documents but there is no information. Is there a way to add SIP plugin or SIP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not exist in Smartface. But, when plugin support becomes available, you can use your plugin. 
You can check it from the roadmap : http://www.smartface.io/roadmap/

Comment: Ok, thank you. But is it possible to use an external js file like sipML5, JsSIP or Sip.JS. Because i read a guide about that i can use external js files but there is not enough explanation about that. Or do you suggest to use webview to use SIP over an external url. Thank you in advance.